# init.vim: E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#'

Tags: vimrc, neovim, vimscript, buffers, alternate-file

I have a problem with adding a keymap to delete all my buffers.

Namely, I used the following map in my `init.vim` file ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071865/17342313)):

```
nnoremap <leader>B :%bd|e#|bd#<CR>
```

And I get the following error, saying there is no substitute for the "#" character:

```
E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#': e#
```

The above command works fine when run outside `VIMRC`.

Is there anyway to actually implement what I want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside `VIMRC` [sic]"? Do you mean "when I type `:%bd|e#|bd#` + Enter" or "when I type `<leader>B` in a buffer that isn't my vimrc" or something else?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The first one. Typing "`:%bd|e#|bd#` + Enter".  Including `#` character in `VIMRC` config leads to this errors.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping `|` characters does the trick:

```haskell
nnoremap <leader>B :%bd\|e#\|bd#<CR>
```

Comment: You can also write `<bar>` (`:help key-notation`). The _reason_ this works is at `:help map-bar`. The first version is equivalent to typing `:nnoremap <leader>B :%bd<enter>:e#|bd#<enter>`, which won't make sense when executing your vimrc at startup.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Oh, I was wondering why it works, now I finally know. Big thanks !